# How to read a specific colum value and also n - 1 from data fram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some set of data in csv format. whereas I have to find total sale amount difference from yesterday and today sales. so could you please explain to access same in a columns

| date | sales value | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-oct-22 | 100 | 0 |
| 11-oct-22 | 120 | 20 |
| 12-oct-22 | 105 | -15 |

How get get date and sales value from pandas dataframe and add next colum diff

No idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

something like this (?):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime(2022, 10, 10), datetime(2022, 10, 11), datetime(2022, 10, 12)], 'sales value': [100, 120, 105]})

df['diff'] = df['sales value'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Comment: This looks great, I'd just make sure it's sorted by date first. Just in case. :)